# Slide left on Viewpager goes to the last

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with cards, that need to be swipeable to the right until the last item is reached, and swipeable to the left until the first item was reached. I don't know how to solve this.

```
SlidesPagerAdapter slidesPagerAdapter = new SlidesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(slidesPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); // To see two cards the sides
        viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewPager.setPadding(32,0,32,0);
        viewPager.setPageMargin(-16);


        // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (position > SlidesPagerAdapter.NUMBER_SLIDES-1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                }
            }

            // Called when the scroll state changes:
            // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();       //ViewPager Type

                if (currentPage == SlidesPagerAdapter.NUMBER_SLIDES || currentPage == 0){
                    previousState = currentState;
                    currentState = state;
                    if (previousState == 1 && currentState == 0){

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? SlidesPagerAdapter.NUMBER_SLIDES : 0);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

When I reach the last item, the behaviour is good. But when I come back to the first element and I try to slide again, the viewpager show me the last element.

1-> 2 -> 3 -> 4 => OK
4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4!!!!

Comment: `ViewPager` is automatically swipe able why  you are manually changing your `ViewPager` item

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            }

            // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            // Called when the scroll state changes:
            // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();       //ViewPager Type

                if (currentPage == SlidesPagerAdapter.NUMBER_SLIDES-1 || currentPage == 0){
                    previousState = currentState;
                    currentState = state;
                    if (previousState == 1 && currentState == 0){

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? 0 : SlidesPagerAdapter.NUMBER_SLIDES-1);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```